# How to load initialState in Reducers (React Redux) from API (mongodb database)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am working on a project and I would like to try integrate the frontend with the backend. The frontend alone is working (I can add events, delete, update) but I actually have a MongoDB database that I'd like to load the data from that is in json format. I would also like to write back to the database if I update or delete certain data.

I first tried a very simplistic approach, which was to get the data from my api and try to leave it in the `initalState` constant, but it failed and my frontend table had the first two rows of hardcoded data, and then it showed up blank.

```js
import axios from "axios";
const API_URL = "http://localhost:8080/api/events";
const initialState = [
    { username: "abc", email: "email@email.com",title: "Title1" ,description: "Description1." },
    { username: "def", email: "test@test.com", title:"Title2",description: "Description2" },
    axios.get(API_URL)
];
  
export const eventReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "ADD_EVENT":
        state = [...state, action.payload];
        return state;
      case "GET_EVENT":
        return action.payload;
      case "DELETE_EVENT":
        const eventFilter = state.filter((event) =>
          event.id === action.payload ? null : event
        );
        state = eventFilter;
        return state;
      case "UPDATE_EVENT":
        const eventUpdate = state.filter((event) =>
          event.id === action.payload.id
            ? Object.assign(event, action.payload)
            : event
        );
        state = eventUpdate;
        return state;
      case "RESET_EVENT":
        state = [{ username: null, email: null, title:null,description:null}];
        return state;
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };

  export default eventReducer;
```

I did try to make an `eventService.js` but I am unsure of how to link it up with the reducer. I hope someone can give me some advice or idea of how I can approach this.

```js
import axios from "axios";

const API_URL = "http://localhost:8080/api";

const getAll = () => {
    return axios.get(API_URL + "events")   
  
};

const get = id => {
    return http.get(`/events/${id}`);
};
const create = data => {
    return http.post("/events", data);
};
const update = (id, data) => {
    return http.put(`/events/${id}`, data);
};
const remove = id => {
    return http.delete(`/events/${id}`);
};

const findByTitle = title => {
    return http.get(`/events/?title=${title}`);
};
const eventService = {
    getAll,
    get,
    create,
    update,
    remove,
    findByTitle
};
export default eventService;
```

UPDATE: I do have some files in my actions folder, but I am unsure how to put this into my store. Furthermore I actually have many different reducers combined into one combinedReducer.

```js
export const retrieveEvents = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const res = await EventDataService.getAll();
      dispatch({
        type: GET_EVENT,
        payload: res.data,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

My component looks something like this right now:

```js
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { useNavigate, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import {Button} from "../Home/Button"; 
import { updateEvent, deleteEvent } from "../../actions/events";
import EventDataService from "../../services/eventService";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import {
  retrieveEvents,
  findEventsByTitle,
} from "../../actions/events";
import "./Event.css";


const Event = ({events, deleteEvent}) => {
  

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  




  return (
      
   
   <div className="event-container">
     
     
      <div className="event-row">
        <Button
          className='btns'
          buttonStyle='btn--addevent'
          buttonSize='btn--large'
          onClick={() => navigate("/events/add")}
        >
          Add Event
        </Button>
        <div className="col-md-10 mx-auto my-4">
          <table className="table">
            <thead className="table-header bg-dark text-white">
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Id</th>
                <th scope="col">Host Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Host Email</th>
                <th scope="col">Event Title</th>
                <th scope="col">Description</th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {events.length > 0 ? (
                events.map((event, id) => (
                  <tr key={id}>
                    <td>{id + 1}</td>
                    <td>{event.username}</td>
                    <td>{event.email}</td>
                    <td>{event.title}</td>
                    <td>{event.description}</td>
                    <td>
                    <Button
                        className='btns'
                        buttonStyle='btn--pink'
                        buttonSize='btn--middle'
                        onClick={() => navigate(`/events/edit/${event.id}`)}
                        
                      >
                        Edit
                      </Button>  
                      </td>
                      <td>                    
                      <Button
                        className='btns'
                        buttonStyle='btn--pink'
                        buttonSize='btn--middle'
                        onClick={() => deleteEvent(event.id)}
                        
                      >
                        Delete
                      </Button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                ))
              ) : (
                <tr>
                  <td>No events found</td>
                </tr>
              )}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    
    
   
  );
};

const mapEventStateToProps = (eventState) => ({
    events: eventState.eventR,
    
});

const mapEventDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    deleteEvent: (id) => {
        dispatch({ type: "DELETE_EVENT", payload: id });
        dispatch(deleteEvent(id));
    },
});


export default connect(mapEventStateToProps, mapEventDispatchToProps)(Event);
```

Comment: You could make another redux action type "INITIALIZE_STORE", then make an api call to get the data and pass that data to "INITIALIZE_STORE", just make the api call when the app initially runs then it will get the current state from the back end. Then to create/update/remove, make a function that sends both an api request to your back end and to an action reducer in redux.

Comment: @ColinHale Are you able to explain / show me how "INITIALIZE_STORE" would look like?

I do have code to get the data, but I am unsure how to pass the data over.

Comment: Sorry, Haven't been on In a couple days, You still stuck?